# How to get that Id when the condition does not match

Tags: mysql

I have a table T. We have multiple records for a particular `user_id` with match `type = "Red Card"`. I just wanted that `user_Id` and `match_id` which has never received a `"Red Card"` in a entire match.

As per the table Image which is attached I would be getting output :
`match_id : 3036` and `3090` and `user_id 4` and `6` respectively[image]

Comment: no effort done before asking

Comment: @AKZhang no effort done even with a bunch of solutions provided... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all fields Use subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT  user_id, match_id  from tbl where match_id NOT IN (
    SELECT match_id from tbl where type = 'Red Card' 
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Although I have tried initially but was not using the subquery..

Answer (score 0):

```
Select match_id,user_id from T where user_id Not IN (Select user_id from T where type = 'Red Card') as k Group By user_id
```

The above query will remove all the users having red cards by first selecting user_id from T who have red cards in the nested  query and then selecting users who are not in the nested statement using "NOT IN" and then grouping by user_id to remove duplicate records.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight :- Edited

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE type <>'Red Card' GROUP BY match_id, user_id
```

This will select all records from the table where there is not "Red Card" and the group by will give you just one record from each couple match/user

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, match_id FROM T WHERE type <> 'Red Card' GROUP BY match_id
```

Because there are duplicate `user_id` and `match_id`-s in the table, I've used `DISTINCT` to select unique ids from the table.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `T` where not exists (SELECT * FROM `T` where `type`="Red card")
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MATCH_ID AND USER_ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE TYPE NOT IN('RED CARD')
```

This Query may help you